# Python - Include another Python script

Tags: php, python, include

I have a question. When you are programming in PHP you can use this to include external php script to current script.

```
include('test_page.php');
```

So you don't have to repeat a code in every script. Is there a way in Python to include another Python script, just like the php page?

Comment: you can use `import`

Comment: Thats for modules, or does it also work with scripts?

Comment: modules are just fancy scripts. `import xy` runs all code in `xy.py`, including but not limited to: creating methods, creating variables, method calls, etc

Comment: so I have to use for example: `import test_script`

Comment: aw, arbazz was faster than me with answering :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python,

you can import the different scripts/modules by using `import` , just make sure they are in same directory and proper function/class.

If modulename.py is an function

> import modulename

if modulename.py is a set a different functions.

> from modulename import particularfunction

Answer (score 0):

If you have "script.py", just make:

```
import script
```

If you have a particular function or a class in the script then:

```
from script import function
```

Remember having it in the pwd. If the script is not in pwd, then you need to append a path to it. So before importing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("PATH_TO_SCRIPT")

import script
```

Comment: If I want to make a database connection in an include, I get the error: `if not self._cnx:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
`

Comment: What type of the database do you have? And how do you create this connection? Normally you create connection in the main script, via methods provided with other imported modules and scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to reuse code, or a code fragment, import does not work, because it treats the code as a component of whatever package it is stored with. import is good for subroutines/method addressability, not much else

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).